# How to upload source version to Azure Setting using curl?

Tags: bash, curl, azure-web-app-service

My objective is simple: get hold of the last commit hash when I run my app

attempts:

1. I started to use `git-last-commit` package but where the app run, it's a normal directory, and the repository is outside this folder

`/config
 /deployments
 /diagnostics
 /ipaddr_0
 /locks
 /repository
 /wwwroot`

the website runs inside `wwwroot` and git repo is in `repository`. I couldn't get hold of it programmatically.

2. So I tried the Kudu API and it's as easy as a `curl` POST ... but how can I pass the commit has as a curl data?

I've tried:

`$ git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%H" | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://$AZURE_LOGIN:$AZURE_PASS@$AZURE_APPNAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings -d '{ "SOURCE_VERSION":"&> /dev/stdin" }'`

and

`$ git log -n1 --pretty=format:"%H" | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://$AZURE_LOGIN:$AZURE_PASS@$AZURE_APPNAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings -d '{ "SOURCE_VERSION":"@d" }'`

only to find that it sends literally what I write and not the piped value

[image]

The idea was to have this as a Bitbucket pipeline step to be executed for every deployment...

Does any of you have some trick to accomplish this?